# Executing Oracle Stored Procedure (PL/SQL) in ASP.NET MVC Core(C#)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, plsql, oracle11g

I've been searching but i do not fully understand how to execute the Stored Procedure through my application and then, commit the transaction. Do note that i am connected to an **Oracle 11g** database.

Take a look, this is my function, i tried to something like this but it does not seem correct to me:

```
 public void CreateRow(Person person)
        {
            using SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_InserNewRow", con);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE", person.CODE);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", person.NAME);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LASTNAME", person.LASTNAME);

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

        }
```

This is my Model cs file:

```
public class Person{
        public int CODE { get; set; }
        public string NAME { get; set; }
        public string LASTNAME { get; set; }
    }
```

This my my Oracle Stored Procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_InserNewRow(
                    CODE IN NUMBER,
                    NAME IN VARCHAR,
                    LASTNAME IN VARCHAR) AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO MyTable(CODE,NAME,LASTNAME) VALUES (CODE, NAME, LASTNAME);

END SP_InserNewRow;
```

> What is the correct way to execute it through MVC?
>
> How can i COMMIT the transaction?
>
> Is there exist any different while trying to execute it in Oracle11g and Oracle12?

---

EDIT:

```
readonly string connectionString = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxxxxxxxx)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=PROD)));User Id=xxx;Password=xxxx;"

public IEnumerable<Person>GetPersonList
        {
            var listPerson = new List<Person>();

            using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
            {

                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from myview", con);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.InitialLOBFetchSize = 1000;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                con.Open();
                OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read()){
                var list = new Person();
                    list.CODE = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CODE"].ToString());
                    list.NAME = dr["NAME"].ToString();
                    list.LASTNAME = dr["LASTNAME"].ToString();

                    listPerson.Add(list);
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            return listPerson;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use OracleConnection instead of SqlConnection

```
using Oracle.DataAccess;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

public DataTable GetHeader_BySproc(string unit, string office, string receiptno)
{
    using (OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection(DatabaseHelper.GetConnectionString()))
    {
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cmd.InitialLONGFetchSize = 1000;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE", person.CODE);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", person.NAME);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LASTNAME", person.LASTNAME);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Also test your SP by executing in DBMS.

Comment: Hey pal, thank you very much for replying; i do not fully understand 2 things?
1)How did you get using **Oracle.DataAccess;using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;** working?How did you set your connectionstring?How do you manage the COMMIT operation?

Comment: 1) Assuming that you are using Visual Studio, you can add Oracle DataAccess pkg from Nuget package manager and use these libraries. 2) DatabaseHelper.GetConnectionString() is a function which returns my connection string. you can pass your string directly in the constructor `new OracleConnection("your string")`. Although it is recommended that you use static function. So thatif you change your connection string, you don't have to find each connection and change. You will change only in the static function and it will be good to go

Comment: To Commit you can simply use commit clause in your stored procedure just like other set of queries. You can learn the syntax with examples of COMMIT statement here. [oracle COMMIT](https://www.educba.com/oracle-commit/)

Comment: Pal, take a look: i have edited my question: is it correct?

Comment: yes seems good to me. But you can tell better after running your code. If it is working or not